# Chart control in ASP.NET 4.0 programmatically in C#

Tags: asp.net

I have problem with this chart of a Chart control in ASP.NET 4.0 programmatically

I can not show the values in the SeriesChartType FastLine.

I have added in the script:

```
Chart1.Series["Price"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

But the values are not shown.

What am I missing?

What's wrong with this code?

Thank you in advance.

My code below.

```
        Chart1.Series.Add("Price");
        Chart1.Series["Price"].YValueMembers = "Price";
        Chart1.Series["Price"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
        Chart1.Series["Price"]["LabelStyle"] = "Center";
        Chart1.Series["Price"]["PointWidth"] = "0.85";
        Chart1.Series["Price"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        Chart1.Series["Price"].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
        Chart1.Series["Price"].LabelForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 128);
        Chart1.Series["Price"]["LabelStyle"] = "Top";
        Chart1.Series["Price"].Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(153, 153, 255);
        Chart1.Series["Price"]["PixelPointDepth"] = "1.0";
        Chart1.Series["Price"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";
        Chart1.Series["Price"].BorderWidth = 3;
        Chart1.Series["Price"].MarkerColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Marker` and `DataPointLabels` are not supported for `FastLine` chart.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489249(v=vs.140).aspx):

```
Some charting features are omitted from the FastLine chart to improve performance. 
The features omitted include control of point level visual attributes, markers, data point labels, and shadows.
```

So if you want to show label/datapoints, use `Line` chart instead.